# error Sql query with datetime

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, datetime

I got a error when I do the follow:

`DateFrom` has as datatype of `datetime`

[image]

My C# code:

```
string strQuery = "Select * FROM Agenda Where   DateFrom='" + Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.Date + "' ";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strQuery, Global.myConn);
da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
da.Fill(Global.dsAgenda, "Tabel");
ddlActivity.DataSource = Global.dtAgenda;
ddlActivity.DataBind();
```

Calendar1 type:

[image]

Error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: What format is `Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.Date` in? Print it out and check. It's trying to cast it to a date (to compare) and failing. Please indicate what kind of database and version. SQL Server?

Comment: @realnumber3012 How do you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should prefer using [`parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx):

```c#
string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Agenda WHERE DateFrom = @Date";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strQuery, Global.myConn);
command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
 Convert(DateTime,Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.Date,103)
```

Comment: I use this: Convert.ToDateTime(Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.Date)

The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.